# Missing files on preserved directories structure (osx)

Tags: macos, filesystems, file-recovery

I'm missing all files from a particular folder inside a partition. What I find odd is that all the folder structure remain intact, but it have 0KB. I've `ls` from shell to be sure it's not a finder problem.

Is there any disk file/info that might got corrupted and could be messing up with this files?

EDIT:
`diskutil list` output:

```
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         303.3 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
4:                  Apple_HFS Data                    1.7 TB     disk0s4
```

The affected partition id `Data` (disk0s4) and file system is `Journaled HFS+`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's the folder structure like? What partition is this? (What filesystem?)

Comment: @slhck have updated the question with the relevant data. About the folder structure I have a lot of folders and files, from which only 2 folders are missing the child's files... but I guess theirs names should be irrelevant.